# Do "operative" and "valid" have the same meaning in legal terms?

Tags: adjectives, legalese

I found this question when reading a machine manual.  In the part about Guarantee, it said "The guarantee will not be *operative* if any of the following apply:"

My question here is that can *operative* be used in here or is *valid* a more appropriate choice for this situation.

P.S. The manual is a translated version.

Thanks

Comment: While _operative_ is understandable here, I agree that _valid_ would be a better choice. I think it's even more common to write, “The guarantee will be **void** if. . . .”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example given, there are numerous ways for the guarantor to say **no**:

> - not operative
> - invalid
> - void
> - null and void
> - terminated
> - inoperative
> - cancelled
> - disallowed
> - not in effect
> - rescinded
> - rejected
> - abandonned
> - surrendered
> - [and probably many others]

Lawyers get paid by the word (well, by the hour, but it amounts to the same thing), so you will often find several used in tandem.

> *This warranty will be deemed void, inoperative and terminated if you ...*

There is no meaningful difference between the two you offer.